# How is REML used in gls?

Tags: generalized-least-squares, reml

I am trying to understand gls and I have two questions:
(1) How are the standard errors of the coefficients calculated?
(2) what role REML plays in gls?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69757284/gls-reml-vs-ml-and-comparison-to-lm

Comment: Yes, thank you very much